# Ionic AngularJS Error while interpolating

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript, ionic-framework

I'm building an ionic app which will display video hosted at Wistia.

My view html as follow:

```
<div class="wistia-iframe-container">
    <iframe class="wistia-iframe content" src="{{filesCtrl.getWistiaURL(file.path)}}" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" class="wistia_embed" name="wistia_embed"></iframe>
</div>
```

Where ***filesCtrl.getWistiaURL(file.path)*** will return the full url of the wistia video.

And my angularJS in coffeescript as follow:

```
getWistiaURL: (path) ->
  'http://fast.wistia.net/embed/iframe/' + path
```

Upon runtime i got the following error:

> Error: [$interpolate:interr] Can't interpolate:
>   {{filesCtrl.getWistiaURL(file.path)}} Error: [$sce:insecurl] Blocked
>   loading resource from url not allowed by $sceDelegate policy.

This error only happened when i put {{filesCtrl.getWistiaURL(file.path)}} as the iframe src value.

There is no error if I simply display it as text content.

```
<p>{{filesCtrl.getWistiaURL(file.path)}}</p>
```

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a security issue in angularjs.

The solution is :

1. inject $sce to your controller
2. return the url in $sce bracket

   ```
   return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(url);
   ```
3. use ng-src instead of src

Although I still suggest you to use an directive to wrap iframe, then change the src directly using dom api.